# login form loading homepage when clicking input box

Tags: jquery, forms

https://www.livingbank.org/user/sign_in

clicking either of the 2 empty input boxes immediately loads the homepage.  I see nothing in the code that would be causing this to happen.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Seems to be happening in all browsers.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have two lengthy minified scripts on that page and I'm guessing that at least one is binding to the input fields of that page. What do those scripts do?

Comment: Also, look at the `div.container` element. There appears to be an event handler bound to its `click` handler.

Comment: Your `<img>` tag with the main logo on the page does not have a closing tag. The browser could be getting confused and is letting the `<a href="/">` tag above it to bleed over into the rest of the page. Just thinking about loud here...

Comment: It's also worth taking a look at the W3C validator results: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.livingbank.org%2Fuser%2Fsign_in&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1):

look in "admin-*****.js". at the end of document just remove the pointed lines:

```
$("div.container").each(function () {
    $(this).height() > e && (e = $(this).height())
}), $("div.container").height(e), $(".container").click(function () {
--> var e = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
--> e && (window.location = e)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking any of the container will relocate you to the home page. Not just the two empty input boxes.

Remove the click attribute on .container.